# Python How to pair two list by lambda and map

Tags: python, lambda

For example, I have following two lists

listA=['one', 'two' , 'three']
   listB=['apple','cherry','watermelon']

How can I pair those two lists to get this output, using `map` and `lambda`?

```
one apple
two cherry
three watermelon
```

I know how to do it by the list comprehension,

```
[print(listA[i], listB[i]) for i in range(len(listA))]
```

but I can't figure out a `map` and `lambda` solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `zip()`?

Comment: This is the standard use case for `zip()`.

Comment: `print(..)`? Why `print`? Furthermore this looks like homework.

Comment: You can't use list comprehension in your case.

Comment: Do **not** use `print` within a list-comprehension. That is *really bad style*, because it uses a side-effect inside a functional construct.

Answer (score 36):

Here what I got based on what you need (map and lambda),

Input:

```
listA=['one', 'two' , 'three']
listB=['apple','cherry','watermelon']
list(map(lambda x, y: x+ ' ' +y, listA, listB))
```

Output:

```
['one apple', 'two cherry', 'three watermelon']
```

Answer (score 16):

The easiest solution would be to simply use `zip` as in:

```
>>> listA=['one', 'two' , 'three']
>>> listB=['apple','cherry','watermelon']
>>> list(zip(listA, listB))
[('one', 'apple'), ('two', 'cherry'), ('three', 'watermelon')]
```

I guess it would be possible to use `map` and lambdas, but that would just needlessly complicate things as this is really the ideal case for `zip`.

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension and zip:

```
listA=['one', 'two' , 'three']

listB=['apple','cherry','watermelon']

new_list = [a+" "+b for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
```

Output:

```
['one apple', 'two cherry', 'three watermelon']
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider there are two lists such as list1,list2. we can pair them in the list or tuple type.

```
list1=['1', '2' , '3']
list2=['3','2','1']
output = list (map (  lambda x,y: [x,y], list1,list2    ))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '3'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '1']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like below:

```
for item in zip(list_1, list_2):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

specifically using map and lambda as asked...

```
list(map(lambda tup: ' '.join(list(tup)), zip(listA,listB)))
```

though I'd probably break that up to make it more readable

```
zipped   = zip(listA,listB)
tup2str  = lambda tup: ' '.join(list(tup))
result   = list(map(tup2str, zipped))
# ['one apple', 'two cherry', 'three watermelon']
```

EDITED - per comment below, `listCombined = list(zip(listA,listB))` was a waste

Comment: Don't use `list(zip(listA,listB)))`... **why are you making a list out of your zip iterator?** That defeats the whole purpose.